# Taps vs Long Press on UITableViews - why are taps are not selecting rows when long presses are?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've noticed a bug with some test code running in the simulator where the `UITableView:tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not being fired if I tap the table view, but is being fired if I tap and hold for a fraction of a second. 0.2 of a second seems to be the magic number.

I've noticed the same thing with another project (not mine) where it's quite obvious that taps are not triggering row selection, but long presses are.

I've been trolling the doco and everything I read says taps should work. Does anyone have any info on why they appear not to be in some cases? Have I missed a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Found it. The problem was that the UITableView had delaysContentTouches turned on. Turning this off ment that touches got through to the cells faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a small delay before firing the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method because the UI subsystem has to discern between tapping a cell, scrolling the table view and accidental touches. I don't think it's actually a bug.